# In Anaconda, how to install the conda root kernel (or make it appear)?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

For some reason, the Jupyter notebook in Anaconda has only one kernel on my Mac (Sierra), which is Python 3. How should one install the conda root kernel, or maybe make it appear should it be disabled?

Comment: Huh? Is this for a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Yes. Question is fixed.

Comment: So, how many conda environments do you have? Did you install Anaconda 3 or Anaconda 2? What other kernels are you expecting to see available?

Comment: In the "environment" section of Anaconda, there is only a "root" environment listed. I installed the Python 3.6 version of Anaconda, so the Python 3 kernel is expected. However, I need the conda root kernel just because the code I am working on returns errors in the Python 3 kernel but runs fine in Python [conda root] (this is how it behaves on other Macs).

Comment: What? What is the "environment section" of Anaconda? Are you using `conda env list`? What errors are you getting? I imagine the Python 3 kernel corresponds to your conda root environment. You need to provide more details *in the question itself*. I'm on a Mac, and I use many different conda envs as root kernels... so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Also, did you already have a Python installation on your computer that already had Jupyter, and *then* you installed Anaconda? This might be an issue with the binary that is being pointed to by `jupyter`. If that is the case, you should share the output of `which jupyter`

Comment: I completely uninstalled Canopy, Anaconda, and Python on my computer, and then installed just Anaconda.

Comment: Oh, I just meant that, in Anaconda Navigator, the left hand side of the program's window has options like "home" "environment", "projects (beta)", etc., and if I click on "environment", the only branch listed there is "root". So my problem is that, in the "home" page, if I click "Jupyter", and try to make any document in the browser page of Jupyter, the only kernel I can choose is Python 3.

Comment: Again, you need to add *more details to the question itself*. What errors are you encountering? What are you seeing, and how are you seeing it, and what do you expect to see?

Comment: My code has a ValueError when using Python 3; but this is not the question I am asking -- I am asking whether it is possible to use a kernel called "Python [conda root]" when the only kernel available to me seems to be "Python 3", and if so, how this can be done. I have described to the fullest extent I can what I know about the issue, barring screenshots. As it seems to me, I have stated everything you need: "what issue I am encounting" "what I am seeing" "how I am seeing it" and "what I expect to see".

Comment: I am really at lost how to better describe it further, and please understand that ...people who are essentially newcomers to programming and multiple coding schemes can encounter technical issues too.

Comment: I'm saying you should put all this information you've added *as a comment* into the *question itself*. You can **edit** your original question. You can post the *full error message* there as well, including the *full stack trace*.

Comment: Again, you say "that is not the question I'm asking", but I ask because to me it seems like there isn't a difference between "Python [conda root]" and the "Python 3" kernels. They *are probably the same things*, that is, "Python 3" *is* your root kernel (which all that means is that it corresponds to your root conda env, but if you have a fresh install there should only be a single env).

Comment: It is really helpful to know that Python [conda root] is likely the same thing as Python 3. Thanks for that -- I will ask a separate question for my issue!